# How to solve pdblp Time out issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bloomberg

I am using Python to download some data from bloomberg. It works most of the time, but sometimes it pops up a 'Time Out Issue`. And after that the response and request does not match anymore.

[image]

The code I use in the for loop is as follows:

```
result_IVM=con.bdh(option_name,'IVOL_MID',date_string,date_string,longdata=True)
volatility=result_IVM['value'].values[0]
```

When I set up the connection, I used following code:

```
con = pdblp.BCon(debug=True, port=8194, timeout=5000)
```

If I increase the timeout parameter (now is 5,000), will it help for this issue?

Comment: "If I increase the timeout parameter (now is 5,000), will it help for this issue?" - did you try that?

Comment: The timeout issue does not happen all the time, so I am not sure whether it finally resolves the issue, or just by luck.

Comment: Have you asked Bloomberg? (press F1 F1 on the terminal)

Comment: yes, it will help. That's what I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to increase the *timeout* to 5000 or even 10000 then test for few times. The default value of *timeout* is 500 milliseconds, which is small!

The TIMEOUT Event is triggered by the blpapi when no Event(s) arrives within  milliseconds

The author of pdblp defines timeout as:

> timeout: int   Number of milliseconds before timeout occurs when
>   parsing response.   See blp.Session.nextEvent() for more information.

Ref: https://github.com/matthewgilbert/pdblp/blob/master/pdblp/pdblp.py

Comment: Got it! Thank you